# Recover files using rdiff-backup command

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, rdiff-backup

I am trying to understand the rdiff-backup command which is already implemented to do backups.My question is What is the command to restore all files in one .gz backedup file using rdiff-backup command.Your comments have been very useful.

If i have files like

Available increments are:

```
   Time                       Size        Cumulative size
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Sun Jul 25 23:31:34 2010         4.19 GB           4.19 GB   (current mirror)
  Sat Jul 24 23:31:34 2010         1.28 MB           4.19 GB
  Fri Jul 23 23:31:34 2010         0 bytes           4.19 GB
  Thu Jul 22 23:31:34 2010         1.26 MB           4.19 GB
  Wed Jul 21 23:31:37 2010         1.11 MB           4.19 GB
  Tue Jul 20 23:31:33 2010         1.23 MB           4.20 GB
```

There will be many .gz files so lets say iwant to recover all the data till Thu Jul 22 23:31:34 2010  .How do i do it.How to restore all the file in a .gz file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you are backing up a tarball which lives in a directory? if so, you'll have to restore the full file at some point in time. It usually works like:

`rdiff-backup -r time file /destination/directory`

so, for example, say you are trying to recover what's in a directory called example from your rdiff root dir:

`cd /dir/of/rdiff/backup`

`rdiff-backup -r 3D example /tmp/newcopy`

and it'll get you the copy as from 3 days ago and put it in `/tmp/newcopy`

read the man page, section `RESTORING`.

Comment: Can u please let me know what is the specific time format that needs to be entered.There is no clear documentation for the time format that  needs to be specified when restoring

Comment: Time format like 21 23:31:37 2010 ?

Answer (score 1):

More info on the time format can be found in the rdiff-backup man page under "TIME FORMATS".